# Not load css in asp.net web form

Tags: css

Part of css file is not loading  in page - sometimes

Address Css File Is :

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/content/main.css" type="text/css" />
```

and

i removed browser cache...

Plese Help me

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this bit:

```
real="stylesheet"
```

It should be:

```
rel="stylesheet"
```

Also it should be `link` not `style`

Resulting in this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/content/main.css" />
```

Comment: @user2231235 are you sure the href is correct also clear the cache to make sure

Comment: @user2231235 try changing your href to `content/main.css` instead of `~/content/main.css`